# How to determine which type of crypto is used in a text file?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

is there a tool or a way to determine which type of crypto is used in this type of text:

```
U3RlZ2Fub2dyYXBoeSBpcyB0aGUgYXJ0IGFuZCBzY2llbmNlIG9m
IHdyaXRpbmcgaGlkZGVuIG1lc3NhZ2VzIGluIHN1Y2ggYSB3YXkgdGhhdCBubyBvbmV=
LCBhcGFydCBmcm9tIHRoZSBzZW5kZXIgYW5kIGludGVuZGVkIHJlY2lwaWVudCwgc3VzcGU=
Y3RzIHRoZSBleGlzdGVuY2Ugb2YgdGhlIG1lc3M=
YWdlLCBhIGZvcm0gb2Ygc2VjdXJpdHkgdGhyb3VnaCBvYnNjdXJpdHkuIFS=
aGUgd29yZCBzdGVnYW5vZ3JhcGh5IGlzIG9mIEdyZWVrIG9yaWdpbiBhbmQgbWVhbnMgImNvbmNlYW==
bGVkIHdyaXRpbmciIGZyb20gdGhlIEdyZWVrIHdvcmRzIHN0ZWdhbm9zIG1lYW5pbmcgImNv
```

Comment: Looks like whatever it is has been BASE64 encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This obviously is not an encryption but a simple coding with Base64 coding:

The decoded text message is:

> Steganography is the art and science of writing hidden messages in
>   such a way that no one, apart from the sender and intended recipient,
>   suspects the existence of the message, a form of security through
>   obscurity. The word steganography is of Greek origin and means
>   "concealed writing" from the Greek words steganos meaning "co...

By googling the whole text message, you would find [this page in princeton university](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Steganography.html).

For decoding the message I used [this website](http://www.base64decode.org/) apparently there are a lot more ways to do that. You may access to more informations about Base64 in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

> Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs to be stored and transferred over media that is designed to deal with textual data.

You may recognize Base64 encoded messages by the signs "==" and "=" in ending of the message and all other must be simple alphabets in lower and uppercase, and also numbers.